# Документация по ClearCase

Tags: clearcase, контроль-версий, документация

Если кто знает, подскажите где можно кратко прочитать про ClearCase?

Comment: уточните вопрос что конкретно вас интересует? если информацаия по коммандам тогда можно так:

clearcase help >> ~/readme.txt

Answer (score 1):

[ClearCase - система конфигурационного и версионного контроля](http://citforum.ru/programming/rational/clearcase_new.shtml)